# Фильтр Гаусса, обработка изображения с помощью процессов и потоков

Tags: многопоточность

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты!

Есть проблемка. Дано изображение, которое будет обрабатываться фильтром Гаусса, код обработки есть, все прекрасно работает, НО препод для проверки дает картинку 20000x20000 пикселей, и, естественно, моим проходом это будет обрабатываться очень долго. И он сказал, что если поделить картинку на несколько частей и обработать с помощью процессов и потоков, то все должно пройти немного быстрее. В связи с этим, не имея литературы, прошу помощи у тех, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой или знает, как разбить это все на потоки.

Код программы выкладываю для проверки работоспособности и внесения возможных поправок. Реализация программы в QT Creator 5.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
ui->label->clear();
ui->label_2->clear();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QFileDialog *dlg;
dlg=new QFileDialog;
FName=dlg->getOpenFileName();
delete dlg;
old_image.load(FName);
new_image=new QImage(old_image.width(),old_image.height(),QImage::Format_RGB32);
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(old_image));
create_gauss(core_h,core_w,sigma);

float*** tmp=new float**[old_image.height()+(core_h-1)];
    for (int i=0;i<old_image.height()+(core_h-1);i++)
        {   tmp[i]=new float*[old_image.width()+(core_w-1)];
            for (int j=0;j<old_image.width()+(core_w-1);j++)
            {   tmp[i][j]=new float[3];
            }
        }

cpy_img_from_tmp(tmp,core_h,core_w,old_image.height()+(core_h-1),old_image.width()+(core_w-1));

    float*** for_saving=new float**[old_image.height()+(core_h-1)];
    for (int i=0;i<old_image.height()+(core_h-1);i++)
        {   for_saving[i]=new float*[old_image.width()+(core_w-1)];
            for (int j=0;j<old_image.width()+(core_w-1);j++)
            {   for_saving[i][j]=new float[3];
            }
        }

gauss_filter(tmp,for_saving,core_g,core_h,core_w,old_image.height()+(core_h-1),old_image.width()+(core_w-1));
normalize(for_saving,old_image.height()+(core_h-1),old_image.width()+(core_w-1));

    for (int i=0;i<old_image.height();i++)
            for (int j=0;j<old_image.width();j++)
            {
                new_image->setPixel(j,i,qRgb(for_saving[i+core_h/2][j+core_w/2][0],for_saving[i+core_h/2][j+core_w/2][1],for_saving[i+core_h/2][j+core_w/2][2]));
            }
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*new_image));
    new_image->save("new","jpg");
    qDebug() << "Finished!";
}

void MainWindow::create_gauss(int core_h, int core_w, float sigma)
{
    core_g = new float *[core_h];
    for (int i=0;i<core_h;i++)
    {
        core_g[i] = new float [core_w];
    }

    for (int i=0;i<core_h;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<core_w;j++)
        {
            core_g[i][j]=gauss_matrix(i-((core_h-1)/2),j-((core_w-1)/2),sigma);
        }
    }
}

float MainWindow::gauss_matrix(float x,float y,float sigma)
{
return (1/(2*M_PI*sigma*sigma)*exp(-(x*x+y*y)/(2*sigma*sigma)));
}

void MainWindow::cpy_img_from_tmp(float*** tmp, int core_h, int core_w, int t_height, int t_width)
{
//qRed(old_image.pixel(j,i)
for (int i=0;i<core_h/2;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<core_w/2;j++)
        {//Углы
            //R
            tmp[i][j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel(j,i));
            tmp[t_height-1-i][t_width-1-j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
            tmp[t_height-1-i][j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel(j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
            tmp[i][t_width-1-j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,i));
            //G
            tmp[i][j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel(j,i));
            tmp[t_height-1-i][t_width-1-j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
            tmp[t_height-1-i][j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel(j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
            tmp[i][t_width-1-j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,i));
            //B
            tmp[i][j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel(j,i));
            tmp[t_height-1-i][t_width-1-j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
            tmp[t_height-1-i][j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel(j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
            tmp[i][t_width-1-j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,i));
        }
    for (int i=0; i<core_h/2;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<t_width-(core_w-1);j++)
            {//Vertical
                //R
                tmp[i][core_w/2+j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel(j,i));
                tmp[t_height-1-i][core_w/2+j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel(j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
                //G
                tmp[i][core_w/2+j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel(j,i));
                tmp[t_height-1-i][core_w/2+j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel(j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
                //B
                tmp[i][core_w/2+j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel(j,i));
                tmp[t_height-1-i][core_w/2+j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel(j,(old_image.height()-1)-i));
            }

    for (int i=0; i<t_height-(core_h-1);i++)
        for (int j=0;j<core_w/2;j++)
            {//Horizontal
                //R
                tmp[core_h/2+i][j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel(j,i));
                tmp[core_h/2+i][t_width-1-j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,i));
                //G
                tmp[core_h/2+i][j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel(j,i));
                tmp[core_h/2+i][t_width-1-j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,i));
                //B
                tmp[core_h/2+i][j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel(j,i));
                tmp[core_h/2+i][t_width-1-j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel((old_image.width()-1)-j,i));
            }

    for (int i=0; i<old_image.height();i++)
        for (int j=0;j<old_image.width();j++)
            {//Window
                tmp[core_h/2+i][core_w/2+j][0]=qRed(old_image.pixel(j,i));
                tmp[core_h/2+i][core_w/2+j][1]=qGreen(old_image.pixel(j,i));
                tmp[core_h/2+i][core_w/2+j][2]=qBlue(old_image.pixel(j,i));
            }
}

void MainWindow::gauss_filter(float ***tmp, float ***for_saving,float** core_g, int core_h, int core_w, int t_height, int t_width)
{
for (int i=(core_h/2);i<t_height-core_h/2;i++)
       for (int j=(core_w/2);j<t_width-core_w/2;j++)
   {
       for (int m=0;m<(core_h/2)+1;m++)
           for (int k=0;k<(core_w/2)+1;k++)
           {//Red
               for_saving[i][j][0]= for_saving[i][j][0]+tmp[i+m][j+k][0]*core_g[(core_h/2)+m][(core_w/2)+k];
               if (k!=0)
               {for_saving[i][j][0]= for_saving[i][j][0]+tmp[i+m][j-k][0]*core_g[(core_h/2)+m][(core_w/2)-k];}
               if (m!=0)
               {
                   for_saving[i][j][0]= for_saving[i][j][0]+tmp[i-m][j+k][0]*core_g[(core_h/2)-m][(core_w/2)+k];
                   if (k!=0)
                   {for_saving[i][j][0]= for_saving[i][j][0]+tmp[i-m][j-k][0]*core_g[(core_h/2)-m][(core_w/2)-k];}
               }
             //Green
               for_saving[i][j][1]= for_saving[i][j][1]+tmp[i+m][j+k][1]*core_g[(core_h/2)+m][(core_w/2)+k];
               if (k!=0)
               {for_saving[i][j][1]= for_saving[i][j][1]+tmp[i+m][j-k][1]*core_g[(core_h/2)+m][(core_w/2)-k];}
               if (m!=0)
               {
                   for_saving[i][j][1]= for_saving[i][j][1]+tmp[i-m][j+k][1]*core_g[(core_h/2)-m][(core_w/2)+k];
                   if (k!=0)
                   {for_saving[i][j][1]= for_saving[i][j][1]+tmp[i-m][j-k][1]*core_g[(core_h/2)-m][(core_w/2)-k];}
               }
             //Blue
               for_saving[i][j][2]= for_saving[i][j][2]+tmp[i+m][j+k][2]*core_g[(core_h/2)+m][(core_w/2)+k];
               if (k!=0)
               {for_saving[i][j][2]= for_saving[i][j][2]+tmp[i+m][j-k][2]*core_g[(core_h/2)+m][(core_w/2)-k];}
               if (m!=0)
               {
                   for_saving[i][j][2]= for_saving[i][j][2]+tmp[i-m][j+k][2]*core_g[(core_h/2)-m][(core_w/2)+k];
                   if (k!=0)
                   {for_saving[i][j][2]= for_saving[i][j][2]+tmp[i-m][j-k][2]*core_g[(core_h/2)-m][(core_w/2)-k];}
               }
           }
   }
}

void MainWindow::normalize(float***mas, int height, int width)
{
float min,max;
min=mas[0][0][0];
max=mas[0][0][0];

for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    { if (mas[i][j][0]<min) min=mas[i][j][0];
      if (mas[i][j][0]>max) max=mas[i][j][0];}

for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    { mas[i][j][0]=((mas[i][j][0]-min)/(max-min))*255;}

min=mas[0][0][1];
max=mas[0][0][1];

for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    { if (mas[i][j][1]<min) min=mas[i][j][1];
      if (mas[i][j][1]>max) max=mas[i][j][1];}

for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    { mas[i][j][1]=((mas[i][j][1]-min)/(max-min))*255;}

min=mas[0][0][2];
max=mas[0][0][2];

for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    { if (mas[i][j][2]<min) min=mas[i][j][2];
      if (mas[i][j][2]>max) max=mas[i][j][2];}

for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    { mas[i][j][2]=((mas[i][j][2]-min)/(max-min))*255;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать несколько потоков, и каждому передавать какой-нибудь диапазон. 
Например, есть изображение 10х10, "делим" обработку между потоками

1. Поток№1 обрабатывай часть изображения 2х10 и указать сдвиг с левого   верхнего края (либо можно указать диапазон в пикселях с [0,0] до [1,9])
2. Поток№2 тоже что и у первого только сдвиг другой (в пикселях с [2,0] до   [3,9])
3. ... еще потоки
4. ?????
5. Profit

Comment: но если использовать только потоки,то тогда программа работать от этого быстрее не будет,необходимо использовать процессы...а насколько я знаю,они вызывают отдельные программы,а не куски кода или функции...как в этом случае быть?

Answer (score 0):

Разделение на несколько процессов - это наверное уже слишком, а вот использование многопоточности однозначно даст значительный прирост в производительности.

Вы можете выбрать один из двух вариантов. Первый предполагает "нарезание" исходного изображения на некоторое количество более мелких частей, тогда как второй может быть основан на распараллеливании уже имеющегося кода, обрабатывающего картинку как единое целое.

При выборе первого варианта следует учитывать необходимость "нарезки" с так называемым нахлёстом областей друг на друга, т.к. если брать не взаимосвязанные соседними пикселями части, то итоговый результат будет значительно отличаться от того, как если бы "нарезка" не производилась и всё изображение обрабатывалось целиком.

Второй вариант в Вашем случае средствами Qt, относящимися к теме многопоточности, реализовать будет довольно проблематично в том плане, что уж очень много всяческих конструкций и циклов, собранных в одном методе. Проще говоря, код больше подходит к C-шной методике, нежели чем к C++, а потому без приложения усилия его будет трудно "подогнать" для использования тем же `QtConcurrent` или `QThread`. Можно конечно бездумно "напихать" с агитпромом "зажарится как-нибудь", но часто это не срабатывает.

В этом случае можно поступить проще - использовать, например, OpenMP. Многими компиляторами (вот только насчёт msvc не уверен, пусть меня поправят, т.к. не пользуюсь им) данная библиотека поддерживается из коробки.

Если нужно распараллелить какой-нибудь цикл, достаточно на строке, предшествующей ему добавить всего одну строку: `#pragma omp parallel for`. В Qt-проект OpenMP подключается также достаточно просто. Добавьте в файл проекта следующие строки (для mingw):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
```